# webauthn yubico example not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, webauthn

I'm trying to run the this project: https://github.com/YubicoLabs/java-webauthn-passwordless-workshop

On Chrome and Edge it works fine, but with Firefox I can't register my Yubikey (no Error Log, Key does not light up and waits for a touch) or authenticate with a previously registered Key (Key lights up and notices the touch)(DOM Exception: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable)

Now I'm quite curious what is causing this behaviour. Is it a Problem with my Firefox config? (aboout:config wenbauthn variables are true) Or is something wrong with the project?

Using:

- Win 10
- Firefox 80.0.1 (also tried 71)
- Security Key by Yubico

Comment: The [Documentation](https://github.com/YubicoLabs/java-webauthn-passwordless-workshop/blob/master/1_Getting_Started/README.md) says it is compatible with edge it means just browser based on chrominium

Comment: Can you please check the domain is correct (127.0.0.1 is not allowed, you shall use "localhost") and corresponds to the RP ID.